# .htaccess change the main configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I want to change the main Apache settings in my server.

Usually what I do is to modify the .htaccess in each website I host in my server.

What I want to do now is to change the general settings of the .htaccess that will automatically affect all the domain names hosted in my server.

Is this possible?

I have full root access.

Please let me know.

For example I want to limitate the usage of certain file extensions. Instead of doing this in each .htaccess I have in each site on my server, I want to do it once for all.

Let me know which file I have to modify in order to do it.

Thank!

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify the main Apache configuration file, which will be in one of several places (`/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` or `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` would be the two most likely options, for RedHat- and Debian-derived systems, respectively).